# Where to add menu to work in all activities

Tags: android, menu

I have a menu.xml and the code to show the menu in action bar. Do i have to add the code in every activity? Cause after this i use a switch case to get click, and more code, so i dont thing its the wright way to copy-paste the same code in every activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
```

Is there a better way to do it as to work in all app (all activities)?

Comment: Consider object oriented abstraction or composition to work with problems like this. Google those it's going to help you in many ways going forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a BaseActivity class.

```
public class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
       return true;
     }
}
```

Now all activities that extend your base activity will have the same menu.

Comment: That works thanks. Should i move the code for menu to base activity? Cause menu shows up but not working.

Comment: If you want the same behaviour in all activities then yes you should :)

Comment: Yes! Everything worked like charm. Thank you a lot! Exactly what i need!

Answer (score -1):

this is a guide for [Android Menu](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus)
this is an example menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/new_game"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_new_game"
          android:title="@string/new_game" />
    <item android:id="@+id/help"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_help"
          android:title="@string/help" />
</menu>
```

And then inflating it within your activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.game_menu, menu);
    return true;
}
```

whe item clicked:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle item selection
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.new_game:
        newGame();
        return true;
    case R.id.help:
        showHelp();
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

good luck and read the doc official for android